# Get an Integer with Flutter from the Cloud Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am new at Flutter and I try to build an App. I want to Display an double on a Textwidget from Cloud Firestore.

My CloudFirestore look like this:

[image: 1]

How can I read the double of 200 in a TextWidget and Displays all the time the new value?

I have create a function to add Integer on the specific logged In User Mail what looks like this:

```
geldNew = _firestore.collection('guthaben').doc(loggedInUser?.email).set({
  'geld': geld,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StreamBuilder` and the snapshots to stream the value, so when there's a change, the UI gets updated automatically like so:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('guthaben')
              .doc("loggedInUser?.email")
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
            return Text((snapshot.data!.data() as Map)["geld"].toString());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to get the value just once, you can use a `FutureBuilder` like so:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
          future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('guthaben')
              .doc("loggedInUser?.email")
              .get(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
            return Text((snapshot.data!.data() as Map)["geld"].toString());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```